# compound interest how to calculate the frequency

Tags: java

so basically everything else works, its just the frequency part which has to be annualy, Semi-annualy, quartly or monthly everything is in the code i just dont know how to put it all together in the calculating part in case future and and case present.

```
package compound;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Compound {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        double total;
        double rate;
        double amount;
        String optRate = "optRate";
        double fixedRated = 0;
        double time;
        double n = 0;
        String presOrFut = "presOrFut";
        String timed = "timed";
        String freq = "freq";
        double frequency = 0;

        System.out.println("please enter amount: ");
        amount = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("please enter the rate: ");
        rate = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("rate of daily, monthly or yearly?");
        optRate = scanner.next();
        switch (optRate) {
            case "daily":
                fixedRated = rate / 365;
            case "monthly":
                fixedRated = rate / 12;
            case "yearly":
                fixedRated = rate / 1;

        }    
        //this is my compounding freq which doesnt work 
        //       System.out.println("please enter the compounding frequency: annualy, Semi-annualy, quartly or monthly");
        //         freq = scanner.next();
        //  switch (freq){
        //     case "annually":
        //        frequency = fixedRated/1;
        //    case "semi":
        //      frequency = fixedRated/2;
        //  case "quartly":
        //        frequency = fixedRated/4;
        //  case "mothly":
        //        frequency = fixedRated/12;

        //  }

        System.out.println("enter the lenght of term: ");
        time = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("is it daily, monthly or yearly");
        timed = scanner.next();
        switch (timed) {
            case "daily":
                n = time * 365;
            case "monthly":
                n = time * 12;
            case "yearly":
                n = time * 1;
        }
        System.out.println("future value at end of term or present value? ");
        presOrFut = scanner.next();
        switch (presOrFut) {
            case "future":
                total = amount * (Math.pow((1 + fixedRated/100),n));
            case "present":
                total = amount / (Math.pow((1 + fixedRated/100),n));
            System.out.println("your total is :"+ total);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking but maybe have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo

Comment: You definitely need `break` statements at the end of each `case` clause.  The switch statements, as they stand now, will always drop through to the last `case`.  BTW the switch statements should always have a `default` clause too for error cases.